# ¿Como obtener método Get id desde aplicación de Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms

Tengo un problema con mi aplicación de Xamarin. En concreto no puedo obtener la información del empleado por medio de su id ya que me muestra el error 404 (Not Found).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el API que estoy utilizando:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetId(string id)
    {
        Empleado empleado = new Empleado();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new
                SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT EMPLEADO, NOMBRE, DEPARTAMENTO, PUESTO, FECHA_INGRESO, DATEDIFF(DD, FECHA_INGRESO, FECHA_SALIDA) AS ANTIGUEDAD
                                                       FROM EMPLEADO
                                                       WHERE EMPLEADO = @EMPLEADO", sqlConnection);

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLEADO", id);
                sqlConnection.Open();

                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    empleado.EMPLEADO = sqlDataReader.GetString(0);
                    empleado.NOMBRE = sqlDataReader.GetString(1);
                    empleado.DEPARTAMENTO = sqlDataReader.GetString(2);
                    empleado.PUESTO = sqlDataReader.GetString(3);
                    empleado.FECHA_INGRESO = sqlDataReader.GetDateTime(4);
                    empleado.ANTIGUEDAD = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(5);
                }

                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
        return Ok(empleado);
    }
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<Empleado>ObtenerEmpleado(string codigo)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Concat(Url, codigo));

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Empleado>(response);
    }
```

Empleado.xaml.cs

```
private async void btnConsultar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmpleadoController empleadoController = new EmpleadoController();
        Empleado empleado = await empleadoController.ObtenerEmpleado(txtCod.Text);
        listaEmpleado.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)empleado;
    }
```

El problema es únicamente con el método Get id, ya que el método Get All si me funciona perfectamente.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error 404, lo obtienes pero desde tu API, ya que haces una petición `await httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Concat(Url, codigo))`, revisa que tu petición te responda llamándola desde tu navegador, o desde postman.